# Notice: Undefined index: con in /var/www/lit/adddata.php on line 93

Tags: php

I get this message :

```
Notice: Undefined index: con in /var/www/lit/adddata.php on line 93
```

with this code:

```
$eventLocation = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],"SELECT VENUE_NAME FROM VENUE WHERE VENUE_CODE = '$eventVenueCode'");
```

I do not get the message if I use:

```
global $con:

$eventLocation = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT VENUE_NAME FROM VENUE WHERE VENUE_CODE = '$eventVenueCode'");
```

Is the use of `$GLOBALS` in the first example improper?

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$GLOBALS` itself is global (no need for `global $GLOBALS`), but it's not magically populated by variables you use elsewhere.

You must set it manually with `$GLOBALS["con"] = /* .. */`

Also, don't use globals. Use private variables. The use of globals is *always* improper.

Comment: I think in this case, a DB connection, using globals is even worse

Comment: Most applications only have one database connection so this is a very innocent case, but it is better though to think about dependencies. If you have a function that has no dependency to a database you don't expect it do any reads/modifications.

Comment: I believe that assigning $con outside a function magically populates the $GLOBALS array with con being the key.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I agree, and admittedly I don't see his code in the full context.

Comment: Thanks! I have taken to heart the warning about using $GLOBALS, but still wondering why the code does't work with the  mysqli_query statement. Trying to duplicate, to some extent, the php.net usage definition for $GLOBALS. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php